# Does array[-1] give the last element in the array?

Tags: c, arrays

programming my arduino microcontroller board in C, I noticed a strange behaviour.

Because of an logic mistake in my program the controller accessed the `-1`th element of an integer array.

```
 int array[5];

 array[4] = 27;
 // array[-1] gives 27 now.
```

Is it correct that I get the last element of an array by using `-1` as the element selector?

Comment: Could it be that, due to the same logical error, you first *wrote* to that location and then read what you expected back from it?

Comment: @Irfy I know what you think about but it isn't the case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, accessing elements outside of the index range is undefined behavior. In your case, the element at the address just prior to the beginning of your array is set to 27.

Since accessing array elements in C is nothing more than doing "straight" pointer arithmetic, passing negative indexes is not disallowed. You could construct a legitimate use case where indexes are negative and positive:

```
int raw[21], *data = &raw[10];
for (int i = -10 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    data[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: I ran the program but it didn't crash. I understand that arithmetic operation is taking place. its surprising that gcc compiler doesn't complain as error nor gives any warning. Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 6):

No; `array[-1]` will not access the last element. It's more likely that the memory location just before the array has `27` stored in it. Try this:

```
array[4] = 27;
array[-1] = 0;
```

Then test whether `array[-1] == array[4]`. They will not be equal (assuming your program doesn't crash when assigning to `array[-1]`).

Answer (score 2):

Accessing arrays with index out of bounds  does not always crash your program. If the memory accessed by -1 is under your program control than an undefined value will pop out (which was stored by some other data created by your program). In your case it is mere coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is incorrect according to the Standard. Accessing an element outside the array invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Your implementation might (I doubt it!) provide that functionality; but you really should **not** rely on it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int raw[4], *data = &raw[2];

raw[0]=0;
raw[1]=1; // -1 index for data
raw[2]=2;
raw[3]=3;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++) {
    printf("\nvalue =%d i=%d\n",data[i],i);
}
printf("\nIndex,[-1]=%d\n", data[-1]);
return 0;

}
```

EDIT: Conclusion is that -1 will access last memory location.

Answer (score -4):

If you are referring to C (and you are), then no. If you try to access an array with a negative index, you will get an out of bounds exception. However, Lua implements this exact thing as a feature. If you access a Lua array with an index of -1, it will read the last element of the array. An index of -2 will read the second-to-last element, and so-on.

Side note: you can annoy your coworkers by writing this

```
foo = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}
print(foo.length() * -1])
```

This prints 1. Annoying, isn't it.